# DIV absolute positioning does not work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, css-position

The following code does not work in IE. The DIV does not span entire page despite the fact it is set to `left:0px` and `right:0px`. Body element has big width according to debugger.

Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; background-color: red">
            Some text

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow. Why are you even doing this? Just set your body bg to red. lol

Comment: This is extraction of real task.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the whole page. use `width:100%` and `height:100%`

Answer (score 0):

Yo can't use"left: 0; right: 0; " either left or right and same with top bottom in same container.

Use This

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
    <body>
   <div align="center" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; background-color: red">
        Some text

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is false. You can use left and right at the same time, as well as top and bottom. this also will only enclose the content in the container. Test your code before you make a statement like this.

Comment: Why are you saying one can use `left` and `right` simultaneously while IE does not work with it?

Comment: There is no need to put right and left in same container If I will use left and right in same container last one overwrite the first one that why i have said you can't use the left and right in same container.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, margins are not required. and it is working here in IE also !

```
 position: absolute; width:100%;height:100%;background-color: red;
```